# why add-on script responds multiple times to message from content script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a firefox extension,
I need to check options if it's set to auto start like:

```
//main.js
tabs.on('load', function(tab) {
  app.port.emit("isAutoActive");
  app.port.on("confirmAutomation", function() {
    //do somthing
  });
});
```

I'm emitting a message from popup.js ( content script ) to main.js like

```
self.port.on("isAutoActive", function() {
  //checking localStorage then:
  self.port.emit('confirmAutomation', true);
});
```

the problem is that "do something" runs multiple times, I mean in the number of opened websites, 1 time for the first website load, 3 times for the third time refreshing the same page or opening the third tab.
may you help me on this?

**Edit**

it works fine this way:

```
  tabs.on('load', function(tab) {
      app.port.emit("isautoActive");
    });
    app.port.on("confirmAutomation", function() {
      tabs.activeTab.attach({
        //do something
      });
    });
```

but it'll run "do something" on a wrong tab if user switches to another tab before response from popup.js

Comment: What is the purpose of 'autostart' - can you add more info? I ahve a feeling there is a better way to solve this problem. Why are you using localstorage?

Comment: @canuckistani I'm adding some functionally on text content of website like highlighting. User can set the extension automatically add a panel to every opening tab or just add the panel only for certain tabs manually. I thought I don't have access to localstorage (reading options) in main.js so I need to check it by sending message to content scripts.Am I right?

Comment: The SDK has apis like [simple-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) and [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) you can use for storing small amounts of data. If you have additional storage needs, the SDK also provides [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/indexed-db) and I wrote a higher-level module called [async-storage](https://github.com/canuckistani/jp-async-storage) with a nicer api based on IndexedDB.